# Golfed fixed point combinator

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming

Write a [fixed point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator) in as few characters as possible, in the language of your choice.

- free form (*i.e.*, whatever's shortest): whole program, actual function, code snippet
- you may not use your standard library's if it has one
- you may however extract it from other high-level functions it you'd rather do that than construct it from the bases

Please include a recursive factorial or Fibonacci that uses it as a demo.

In this question, self-reference is acceptable, the aim is solely to remove it from the recursive function it will apply to.

Comment: Is a lazy-language implementation ok? (Would you accept `(define Y(lambda(f)(f(Y f))))` ?)

Comment: Any implementation you can demonstrate with one of the requested examples is ok.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, strictly speaking, the term "Y combinator" refers specifically to a single fixpoint combinator discovered by Haskell Curry, λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x)) .

Comment: @Eelvex: Obviously both answers so far (including the OP's own answer) use the cheating way, so, I guess that makes it okay. :-P Personally, I'd rather go with @Joey's approach and say that only the real (non-self-referential) Y combinator will do. ;-)

Comment: @Chris: Oh my. That's what I had in mind initially, and then I... forgot along the way. It's kind of too late to change now, we'll have to open another question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Haskell: 10 characters

```
y f=f$y f
```

Example of use to create recursive definitions of factorial or nth-Fibonacci:

```
> map ( y(\f n->if n <= 1 then 1 else n*f(n-1)) ) [1..10]
[1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800]

> map ( y(\f n->if n <= 1 then 1 else f(n-1)+f(n-2)) ) [0..10]
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Though, a more common way to use `y` would be to generate these sequences directly, rather than as functions:

```
> take 10 $ y(\p->1:zipWith (*) [2..] p)
[1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800]

> take 11 $ y(\f->1:1:zipWith (+) f (tail f))
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Of course, with Haskell, this is a bit like shooting fish in a barrel! The `Data.Function` library has this function, called `fix`, though implemented somewhat more verbosely.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 37

```
sub f{my$s=$_[0];sub{$s->(f($s),@_)}}
```

Factorial demonstration:

```
sub fact {
  my ($r, $n) = @_;
  return 1 if $n < 2;
  return $n * $r->($n-1);
}
print "Factorial $_ is ", f(\&fact)->($_), "\n" for 0..10;
```

Fibonacci demonstration:

```
sub fib {
  my ($r, $n) = @_;
  return 1 if $n < 2;
  return $r->($n-1) + $r->($n-2);
}
print "Fibonacci number $_ is ", f(\&fib)->($_), "\n" for 0..10;
```

Answer (score 3):

### GNU C - 89 chars

```
#define fix(f,z)({typeof(f)__f=(f);typeof(__f(0,z))x(typeof(z)n){return __f(x,n);}x(z);})
```

Example:

```
#define lambda2(arg1, arg2, expr) ({arg1;arg2;typeof(expr)__f(arg1,arg2){return(expr);};__f;})

int main(void)
{
    /* 3628800 */
    printf("%ld\n", fix(lambda2(
        long factorial(int n), int n, 
            n < 2 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1)
        ), 10));

    /* 89 */
    printf("%ld\n", fix(lambda2(
        long fibonacci(int n), int n, 
            n < 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
        ), 10));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## k2, 12 char

The obvious self-referential implementation is the shortest. This is a sign of good language design. Unfortunately, K isn't lazy, so we can only manage call-by-value.

```
Y:{x[Y[x]]y}
```

This definition should also work in k4 and q without trouble, though I assume k2 for the examples below.

```
  Y:{x[Y[x]]y}
  fac: {[f;arg] :[arg>0; arg*f[arg-1]; 1]}
  Y[fac] 5
120
  fib: {[f;arg] :[arg>1; f[arg-1] + f[arg-2]; arg]}
  Y[fib]' !10
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

A more modest 18 characters lets us exactly transcribe `(λx. x x) (λxyz. y (x x y) z)` into K.

```
{x[x]}{y[x[x;y]]z}
```

Maybe someday (k7?), this could look like `Y:{x Y x}`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 30 Bytes

```
Y=lambda f:lambda a:f(Y(f))(a)
```

Demo :

```
Y=lambda f:lambda a:f(Y(f))(a)
quicksort = Y(
lambda f:
    lambda x: (
        f([item for item in x if item < x[0]])
        + [y for y in x if x[0] == y]
        + f([item for item in x if item > x[0]])
    ) if x
    else []
)
print(quicksort([1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2]))
```

Credits : https://gist.github.com/WoLpH/17552c9508753044e44f

Comment: Python 3 has filter. Also I'm sorry I neglected to mark that comment as a joke

Comment: Python 3 's filter returns a filter object and not a list. It would be less readable or pythonic to use filter.

Comment: it would be less Pythonic, but more in line was [tag:functional-programming], which was my point

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
v_//Z@g_=Z@g~g~v           (* golfed   *)
Z[g_][v_] = g[Z[g],v]      (* ungolfed *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc2xCsIwEAbgPU9xo9ZIW1cNOAluDk4NR7iEth60KYTQReyrx9hRcTm447/vHyk@2pEiO0ppNmXZnHuj8lj6ZU6bAjpycQpMAxRbkRcdjARvEBRcO@1BKagk1PlWBO33NeJR3AL7qO9kh1Y3Oj@hZpTwZLlmqxeiENm@sJ08OcerzfbbPqkVlvCRD7j7V8D2tyC9AQ)

This definition of the [*Z* combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Strict_fixed-point_combinator) uses the Wolfram Language's pattern-matching to make sure that any expression of the form `Z[g]` remains unevaluated as long as the second argument is missing; only the two-argument form `Z[g][v]` matches the above pattern and is replaced by `g[Z[g],v]`, which in turn contains the single-argument form `Z[g]` that remains unevaluated until later. This distinction between an inert single-argument form `Z[g]` and an automatically-substituted two-argument form `Z[g][v]` allows for a controlled recursion process that remains tied to the application of the second argument.

### examples

#### factorial

```
fac[r_, n_] = If[n==0, 1, n*r[n-1]];
Table[Z[fac][i], {i, 0, 10}]
(*    {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}    *)
```

Same with an anonymous function:

```
Table[Z[If[#2==0, 1, #2*#1[#2-1]]&][i], {i, 0, 10}]
(*    {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}    *)
```

Same but using Mathematica's built-in self-reference operator [`#0`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html): we don't actually need a combinator to define [recursive anonymous functions](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Anonymous_recursion#Mathematica_.2F_Wolfram_Language),

```
Table[If[#1==0, 1, #1*#0[#1-1]]&[i], {i, 0, 10}]
(*    {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}    *)
```

#### Fibonacci sequence

```
fib[r_, n_] = If[n<=1, n, r[n-2]+r[n-1]];
Table[Z[fib][i], {i, 0, 10}]
(*    {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}    *)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
{∇(⍎⍺⍺)⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3y2z4lHbhOpHHe0aj3r7HvXuAiLNR71ba///V682fNS5FMi2MnzU3aIBkVMA8nUNNbWReEa16gpAYxRMAA)

An operator whose left operand is a string representing the function to be combinatorified and whose right argument is passed to the function once it is combinatorised. I *think* it's okay to pass the function as a string, but if not, I will delete this answer.

Explanation

```apl
{∇(⍎⍺⍺)⍵}
 ∇(⍎⍺⍺)     ⍝ Equivalent to f ( Fix f )
     ⍺⍺      ⍝ Left operand
   ⍎        ⍝ Evaluate to get monadic operator
 ∇           ⍝ Self-reference (Fix f). Pass as operand to f (or ⍎⍺⍺)
        ⍵    ⍝ Apply the derived function to the right argument ⍵
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 104 bytes

```java
interface C{int t(int n);}interface F{C f();}interface P{C c(F f);static F g(P p){return()->p.c(g(p));}}
```

Based on [*@user*'s Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229753/52210) for [the related *Implement Fix2 combinator* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229602/implement-fix2-combinator).

**Explanation:**

```java
interface C{       // Completed Function interface
  int t(int n);}   //  Using a function that transforms a given integer

interface F{       // Function interface
  C f();}          //  A wrapper to pass the 'Completed Function' as function

interface P{       // Program interface
  C c(F f);        //  Which takes a 'Function' as argument, and returns a 'Completed Function'
  
  static F g(P p){ //  Recursive function that accepts a 'Program' as argument, and returns a 'Function'
    return()->     //   Return a new function, which wraps:
      p.c(         //    A completed call to its own 'Program' interface
       g(          //     Using a recursive call to its own function
         p));}}    //     with the given 'Program' as argument
```

The method to call is `P::g`, which takes `P` as argument and returns `F`. To obtain a completed function `C` from an `F`, we can call `F::f` on it. `P` represents the function to be fixed, and its method `c` takes `F` as argument to prevent immediate evaluation, returning a `C` that represents a complete function to transform a given integer `n` with `C`'s `t(n)`.

**Example Fibonacci implementation:**

```java
P fix = fibonacci -> n -> n>1? fibonacci.f().t(n-1)+fibonacci.f().t(n-2) : 1;
C func = P.g(fix).f();
int result = func.t(input);
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwEETv@YohJwljURd6qRv3EPCtYMix9KAotqs0kYW8Di3G3@6ulUAovSzDzOix2qO@6PR4@Jpn66gOjTY1tiNrkFimk/l0T8pxi0b8sSq2jCjRyLwnTdagRCsqeDmGmobghEwLr4xohZf8cpr9sD9xzZx03@NNW4dxBdzcG@PS2QPOnIkdBeva9w/o0H7KWAUqNPYbG577zmljLNICLo4ie73bipdVJFyayeS/@SjxjCyPRP7X4AwjK9UKhsuldY2aLsRTWOcH2jzkV/GSPd1UksjYA3Y/PdVn1Q2kPG9NYmGq5ZBck8ka64icVtP8Cw)