# Implement Fix2 combinator

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

### Background

The [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) \$\textsf{fix}\$ is a higher-order function that computes the fixed point of the given function.

$$\textsf{fix}\ f = f\ (\textsf{fix}\ f)$$

In terms of programming, it is used to implement recursion in lambda calculus, where the function body does not normally have access to its own name. A common example is recursive factorial (written in Haskell-like syntax). Observe how the use of `fix` "unknots" the recursive call of `fac`.

```haskell
fix f = f (fix f)
fac = fix facFix where
  facFix fac' n =
    if n == 0
    then 1
    else fac' (n - 1) * n
-- which is equivalent to the following recursive function:
fac n =
  if n == 0
  then 1
  else fac (n - 1) * n
```

Now, have you ever thought about how you would do the same for *mutually* recursive functions? [This article](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/fixed-point-combinators.html#Poly-variadic) describes the fully general \$\textsf{Y}^*\$ combinator, which takes a list (or equivalent) of unknotted definitions and returns the list of mutually recursive ("knotted") functions. This challenge will focus on a simpler situation with exactly 2 mutually recursive functions; the respective combinator will be called `fix2` throughout this challenge.

A common example of mutual recursion is `even` and `odd` defined like this:

```haskell
even n =
  if n == 0
  then true
  else odd (n - 1)
odd n =
  if n == 0
  then false
  else even (n - 1)
```

The unknotted version of these would look like this (note that mutually recursive definitions should have access to *every single function* being defined):

```haskell
evenFix (even, odd) n =
  if n == 0
  then true
  else odd (n - 1)
oddFix (even, odd) n =
  if n == 0
  then false
  else even (n - 1)
```

Then we can knot the two definitions using `fix2` to get the recursive `even` and `odd` back:

```haskell
fix2 (a, b) = fix (\self -> (a self, b self))
  where fix f = f (fix f)
let (even, odd) = fix2 (evenFix, oddFix)
```

### Challenge

Implement `fix2`. To be more precise, write a function or program that takes two unknotted black-box functions `fFix` and `gFix` and a non-negative integer `n`, and outputs the two results `(f(n), g(n))` of the knotted equivalents `f` and `g`. Each `f` and `g` is guaranteed to be a function that takes and returns a non-negative integer.

You can choose how `fFix` and `gFix` (and also `fix2`) will take their arguments (curried or not). It is recommended to demonstrate how the even-odd example works with your implementation of `fix2`.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I must admit that the description of this challenge seems to rely on (pseudo?)-code that I find rather difficult to understand.

Comment: It might be easier to read if the `if`s were broken onto multiple lines.  But currently I have no issue reading this.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I replaced some special names with plain arithmetic (which I admit I should have done already), and spread out the if-clauses. Would it help if I explain some of the syntax, like `fix f = f (fix f)` is `def fix(f): return f(fix(f))`, `f x` is a function application `f(x)`, and `\x -> smth` is `lambda x: smth`?

Comment: ... and how do you eliminate the recursion in `fix` itself?

Comment: I think the bits I'm finding difficult are ```facFix fac' n =``` & ```evenFix (even, odd) n =```.  Is ```facFix fac' n =``` the start of a definition of a function ```facFix``` that has 2 arguments: a function ```fac'``` and a number ```n```?  And what is ```(even, odd)``` in the ```evenFix``` function definition?  Sorry, I realise that it sometimes seems amazing that someone else can't easily understand notation that seems to the writer to be obvious...

Comment: @Neil `fix f = (\ x -> f (x x)) (\ x -> f (x x))`

Comment: @DominicvanEssen `facFix` and `evenFix` are curried functions taking two args, and the `(even,odd)` is the first argument of `evenFix` that happens to be a tuple and gets destructed right away.

Comment: I also find the pseudo-code hard to follow. Since `fix` is a higher-order function, `fix f` is a function. So what is `f(fix f)`? My understanding is that `f` takes points, not functions, as inputs

Comment: @LuisMendo `f` takes the completed form of `f` and returns another complete function `Int -> Int`.

Comment: @LuisMendo `fix` is a higher order function, but that does not mean `fix f` is a function.  `fix` takes a function as input but does not necessarily produce one as output.  It's output type is the same as `f`.   `fix` is not an easy function to understand, but the psuedo-code is pretty simple here.  It just reads: `fix f` is the same as `f` applied to `fix f`.  This might seem strange or confusing, but that's the nature of `fix`, it's strange until it's not.

Comment: I upvoted because this challenge is good, but it currently needs more polishing.. As I see it, the challenge got wound up because you are trying to avoid giving a concise equational definition of `fix2`, just like `fix`. I hope I'm wrong :(

Comment: @WheatWizard I see. So `fix` outputs the fixed _points_ of `f`, not a _function_

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 14 bytes

```hs
f l=map($f l)l
```

Takes a two-element list of functions that take two-element lists, and returns a two-element list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY85CsMwEEV7neIXAUmQGKdModYnSGdUCDzGIrJsvITcXhkpmJAu1bxZ/oMZ3PqgEFLqEczoZnVi0CHRk2LjX2gznDF1nUWEEYDvMxjUzNtAEfdlJ2YKK@U7qIgLrloIbv5UNI7DhyOffyUlLUtcWhj0Hx@Ly4yrFWJ0noXoJnbMi48bFP9STBJtXVU3q39XWXds0hs)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 137 bytes

```java
interface L{C g();}interface C{int a(int x);}interface P{C a(L[]l);static L[]z(P[]p){return new L[]{()->p[0].a(z(p)),()->p[1].a(z(p))};}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU@7boMwFN3zFXe0JUBQKUsR6YDUKVWRMiIGFxxKSgwCQ1OQv51ejNM0S1j8OI97zj2xntmn7GuaCiF5c2Qph/0YQk6or25QOOIbGJnPyx0ToZiRfZyU1G8lk0UK@BlIFCc1HRsuu0aA4N8zOhJq7@rYTRxGBlJTai2A9wcoX6mp7j5KHJOWrG3hjRUCxg2AQU1GXxUZnJEjB9kUIo8TYE3@SbUUANOB91y8Z9lrcYHAwABH0YK9A7EcQQAuvIAHzzMx98C9sYuwPWo9crjG4f53aIPy9dWz5loA0yNnILc6dJGEWoCsYcwwCyrtuaJLqcVy@GklPztVJ50at5al0GMxf0tXJe665OmBBFutDFkU21WFSVEbNf0C)

I was actually hoping this would turn out longer so it'd be a better shitpost.

The method to call is `P::z`, which takes two-element array of `P`s and returns a two-element array of `L`'s. To obtain a completed function (`C`) from an `L`, one has to call `L::g` on it. `P` represents a function to be fixed, and its `a` method takes a two-element array of `L`s to prevent evaluation immediately, returning a `C` that represents a complete function that an `int` `n` can be applied to.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 82 bytes

```scala
type R=Int=>Int
type T=(=>Stream[R])=>R
def>(f:Stream[T]):Stream[R]=f.map(_(>(f)))
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CB7cRlanRwSOn6PabviHDg)

This is very similar to Anders Kaseorg's answer, but it takes a lot more effort to avoid stack overflows and infinite recursion in Scala because it doesn't have lazy evaluation by default.

```scala
//The result type, a complete function
type R=Int=>Int
//A function that needs to be fixed. Takes a by-name parameter, a lazily evaluated
//list that contains complete functions, and returns a complete function
type T=(=>Stream[R])=>R
//The meat of the answer. This is practically the same as the Haskell answer.
def>(f:Stream[T]): Stream[R] =
  f.map(    //For every incomplete function in f
   _(       //apply it to
    >(f)))  //the result of applying > on f again (not immediately evaluated)
```

A possible implementation of `evenFix` and `oddFix`:

```scala
val evenFix: T = fns => n => if (n == 0) 1 else fns(1)(n - 1)
val oddFix: T = fns => n => if (n == 0) 0 else fns(0)(n - 1)
```

Note that since `fns` is a by-name parameter, using it more than once causes it to be evaluated again. It can also not be pattern-matched on, since that causes it to be evaluated.